# Djoser simplejwt authentication forbidden(403) while sending JWT <token> to auth/users/me/

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

I am using djoser and simplejwt for authentication and authorization. When I send a post request for authentication to endpoint `http://localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/` it responds with access and refresh token, and again when I pass the `Authorization:JWT <access_token>` to `https://localhost:8000/auth/users/me/` it gives 403 forbidden with:

```js
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

have my settings like

```js
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'PERMISSIONS': {
        'activation': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
        'password_reset': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
        'password_reset_confirm': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
        'set_password': ['djoser.permissions.CurrentUserOrAdmin'],
        'username_reset': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
        'username_reset_confirm': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
        'set_username': ['djoser.permissions.CurrentUserOrAdmin'],
        'user_create': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
        'user_delete': ['djoser.permissions.CurrentUserOrAdmin'],
        'user': ['djoser.permissions.CurrentUserOrAdmin'],
        'user_list': ['djoser.permissions.CurrentUserOrAdmin'],
        'token_create': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
        'token_destroy': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'],
    },
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserSerializer'
    }
}
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
}
```

```js
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICAITON_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ),

}
```

serializers

```js
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers

User = get_user_model()


class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')
```

user model

```js
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, is_staff=False, is_admin=False, is_active=True):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have password")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("First Name must be provided")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Last Name must be provided")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.set_password(password)  # django function change user password
        user.first_name = first_name,
        user.last_name = last_name,
        user.is_staff = is_staff
        user.is_active = is_active
        user.is_admin = is_admin
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user
    # def get_by_natural_key(self, email_):
    #     return self.get(code_number=email_)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_no = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

urls

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path, path, include
from accounts.views import testApi
# from sociallogin.views import FacebookLogin, GoogleLogin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('accounts/', testApi),
    ]
```

Comment: I have similar issue in my react app: both ```http://localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/```  and ```https://localhost:8000/auth/users/me/``` are working in the browser. However, when I try to fech these endpoints from react frontend app , only ```http://localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/``` works.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the baseUrl that you use to called the endpoints (`http://localhost:8000`).

#### solution:

The baseUrl of the frontend app should **exactly match** the one used by django for Starting the development server(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in my case).

Here are my settings:

- React Frontend:

```js
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
  prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState}) => {
    const access = getState().auth.tokens.access
    if (access) {
      headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
      headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${access}`)
    }
    return headers
  },
})
```

- Django Backend:

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
]
```